Shell Errors in Emacs `M-x shell-command` but Not in Terminal
t I've hit a small snag that I'm hoping to get some insights on.
When I call a function or alias using M-x shell-command,
I encounter shell errors that don't appear when I run the same commands directly in the terminal.
Here's what I'm seeing:
/home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom: line 267: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom: line 267: ` +([0-9]))'
/home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom: line 267: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom: line 267: ` +([0-9]))'
Thu Aug 22 09:34

Interestingly, the function or alias still executes correctly,
and the expected output (e.g., the date) is displayed.
However, these preceding error messages only show up when I run the command from Emacs.
According to [1], It seems that +() is extended globbing (extglob).
Since I’m using +([0-9])) in my code,
it’s possible that this is causing the error.
To fix this, I need to enable extended globbing with: bash shopt -s extglob 
Looking for guidance on where to set this.
Thanks !
[1] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713386/msys2-command-works-fine-in-terminal-but-syntax-error-in-script

Add shopt -s extglob at the top of the /home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom file.

@heemayl then emacs gets stuck whenever I try to run any command. I get on results and I need to unfreeze emacs with C-g. I uncomment the shopt line in .bashrc_custom, run the command again, and now it's fine. I still get the errors though.

@heemayl please can you provide your comment as an answere so that I can mark it as answered? the freeze is another problem.

I have added an answer with additional details.

You have a bash extended glob (extglob) pattern in line 207 of file /home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom: +([0-9]), but the extended glob option is not enabled resulting in the syntax error.
To get rid of the error, enable extglob using the shopt builtin before any extglob pattern is used (putting it at the top is recommended along with other shell options so that it's easily noticeable):
shopt -s extglob


Notes:

extglob option is enabled by default on interactive bash instances, so there is no need to do shopt -s extglob in any interactive bash.
You can also put shopt -s extglob in the bash initialization file (perhaps ~/.bashrc in this case?) from where you're source-ing your /home/ychaouche/.bashrc_custom file.

